# How to design validation rules between microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

We have two Microservices (M1 and M2) and each microservice has it's own schema DB1 and DB2.

1. M1 receives the request for registration
2. M1 calls M2 for validation
3. M2 returns validation results (with validation id - VID) to M1
4. M1 completes the registration and persists in DB1 and each registration will have Record Identifier (RID)

My question here is where do we persist the relationship between RID and Validation Results for RID?

Should they be persisted in DB1 (associated to M1) or DB2 (validation schema)?

If the relationship needs to be persisted in M2, then M1 has to make a call to M2 with RID and VID (validation id)

what is the recommended approach in microservices world?

Answer (score 0):

The information provided is not really sufficient for a really valuable answer, but you may consider the following:

1. It seems to me, that you have more than one RID for one VID but only one VID for each RID. If this is true, it seems more reasonable to me to store this 1:M relationship in the Registration DB.
2. In what circumstances do you need the Validation schema information behind the VID?
   What I mean:

- Do you have a method, which returns all the registrations connected to specific VID?
- Or may be, you have a method, returning the Validation schema used for specific registration?

Do you see the difference and why this questions is important?

Finally, you may be interested in [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01553.pdf), especially in chapter 4.4 Decentralisation -> Shared persistence.

You don't share the same storage, but it seems to me that it is possible, that you have split it more than needed and it may be a good idea to combine the Registration and the validation services into one. Of course, this is very speculative statement. But if you are unsure if I am right or not, ask yourself:

- Does other services / clients use the Validation service?
- Does the Validation service represent a dedicated business unit / domain or is it just part of other's unit processes?

And things like that.

And finally: The microservices world doesn't recommend where to put your data, but what to think about, when you decide where to put your data and the main things you may consider, are:

- Your services should be deployed autonomously and should operate autonomously.
- Your services shouldn't share their storage (because of the previous one)
- You should be able to scale individual services by need, without touching the other (this is why we need autonomous deployment and operability)
- The granularity principle is very dependent to your concrete project. When you decide "how much", you should take care of the business domain and the ability to maintain all other principles.

Remark: The principles above are by no means exhaustive, but I hope, that all this gives you some directions to get your job done.

Comment: very thoughtful answer. let's assume, RID is for a person. every update to the person will go through the validations and every time it goes through validation, will have a new VID. RID will not change but depending on the number of updates to the RID, it will have that many VID's so that the user can check the history of validation results.

Comment: > Does other services / clients use the Validation service? for now, no but it is possible to make it as an independent service for all rule validations.

Comment: Do you have a method, which returns all the registrations connected to specific VID? It should be the other way, like for a given person (RID), give me the list of validation results (no of times the record got updated and its validation results).
Or may be, you have a method, returning the Validation schema used for specific registration? we designed validation schema just for storing the validation results, the issue is only with establishing the relationship between the RID and VID (validation result identifier) and where to store the relationship

Comment: So, my assumption was wrong. You have M:M relationship. But the essential here is: "So the user can check the history of validation results". It seems to me that you have a request to M1 for a specific user and the answer of this request will contain links to validation resources in M2, than the user may initiate additional requests to M2 to obtain the full info for a current validation. In this case, it would be reasonable to keep the RID-VID relationship in your M1 DB.

Comment: >  for now, no but it is possible to make it as an independent service for all rule validations.
I wouldn't advise you to make architectural decisions, based on uncertain future. This doesn't mean you must combine them, because other services don't use the validation. It means, that this is not the reason that drives you not to do it. If your life gets more complicated, because you split, than you don't. If in the future your requirements change, you may split it in that future. Of course, if the split makes your life easier and your code more maintainable – split!